# What happens with changed config files when unattended-upgrades runs

Tags: configuration, unattended-upgrades

What happens when unattended-upgrades installs a new version of a package which has a different config file then on my computer? 
Normally you get asked if you want to keep yours or overwrite it with the one in the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages which would result in configuration file prompts are held back by `unattended-upgrades`:

> It will not install packages that require dependencies that can't be
> fetched from allowed origins, and it will check for conffile prompts
> before the install and holds back any package that requires them.

(from [its `README.md` file](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md)).

So any upgrade which would require manual intervention won’t happen automatically; it will only happen the next time you run `apt upgrade` or an equivalent.

This can be configured using the general `apt` `Dpkg::Options` setting (in a configuration snippet in a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`); for example

```
Dpkg::Options {"--force-confold"};
```

will keep the existing version of any conflicting configuration file on upgrade (and `unattended-upgrades` *will* process the upgrade if it is configured in this way). Note however that this option would apply to any `dpkg` invocation by an `apt`-based tool, which may not be appropriate.

Comment: Where do you put that Dpkg::Options setting?

Comment: Anywhere `apt` would read it, it’s a general `apt` configuration setting; since it’s not `unattended-upgrades`-specific it won’t be appropriate in most setups. (I’ve updated my answer to clarify that.)